# Migrate one column of a table to another table's column in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, database-migration

```
field_data_body
+----------+---------------------+
| entry_id | body_value          |
+----------+---------------------+
|  1009    | content             |
+----------+---------------------+
|  1020    |                     |
+----------+---------------------+
|  1025    | more content        |
+----------+---------------------+


i_posts
+------+---------------+
|  id  |     html      |
+------+---------------+
| 1009 |               |
+------+---------------+
| 1020 |               | 
+------+---------------+
| 1025 |               | 
+------+---------------+


i_posts
+----------+---------------------+
| id       | html                |
+----------+---------------------+
|  1009    | content             |
+----------+---------------------+
|  1020    |                     |
+----------+---------------------+
|  1025    | more content        |
+----------+---------------------+
```

Hi, I'm trying to transfer the `body_value` column into the `html` column and am not sure how to execute this. I have a table called `i_posts` and I have all the id's of my posts that i'm trying to transfer. However in the `field_data_body` table it doesn't have content for every single entry_id. Is there a way to move the `body_value` into the html column while keeping the correct `id`? Thanks for any help in advanced!!
 - Blake

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html, search for “multiple tables”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** 
This is what you need.

`UPDATE i_posts AS i, field_data_body AS f SET i.html = f.body_value WHERE i.id =f.entry_id`

I did a small [post](http://www.abelworld.com/update-multiple-tables-column-mysql/) about it.